# How create alarm in cloudwatch for files processed before certain time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

We have metric named processed_file_count which is a TS of 1, which means when we receive a file we call putMetrics on this given metrics with value 1.

For our application to work properly we must receive 5 files everyday(excluding sat and sun) before 13.00 UTC.

How do I create alarm on metric processed_file_count to be invoked if I don't receive 5 files by 13.00 UTC?

I have tried to use add math with expression on metric but i am not able to formulate something for my requirement. Please help.

Comment: Does not sound like a good fit for cloudwatch alarms. Instead I would trigger a lambda at 13:00 and let that lambda perform whatever check you want and then raise an alert if necessary.

Comment: @luk2302 I have done it via little hack. I added formula and where I want to suppress the alarm i have returned the dummy value 10000 and otherwise it will be my metric value . After which i have placed the condition in alarm to set if m1 < 5
IF(HOUR(m1)<13 AND DAY(m1) >5, 10000,m1)